# how do i add elements from two lists together

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

i have two lists like this:

```
l_1 <- list("e","f","g","h","i","k")
l_2 <- list("a","b","c","","","d")
```

how do i get the list l_3 like this `("e a","b f","g c","h","i","k d")`. It is the sum of l_1 and l_2.

Comment: `l3 <- as.list(paste(l_1, l_2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `paste` to combine elements:

```
paste(l_1,l_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

`as.list(paste(l_1,l_2, sep=' '))`
I think.